# Defining the "uniformity" of a dataset

Tags: chi-squared-test, histogram, uniform-distribution

I am working on a few algorithms where I have a list of $N$ samples. Currently I have plotted these into a histogram and have a view of how uniform the values are distributed within an interval, which is quite good as a visualization, although I need a comparable value of how uniform the dataset is, in order to measure how robust it is compared to my other algorithms.

I have been looking at chi-squared test, but could not figure out how it would become helpful in my usecase?

Sample from dataset:

```
8725
462
1492
972
9941
8235
8220
6949
1252
```

Code for importing data and applying chi-squared in `R`:

```
mydata = read.csv2("/opt/doc/stat/uniform_test_1.csv")
x <- sapply(mydata, as.numeric)
chisq.test(x)
```

Result: `X-squared = 1664769844, df = 999998, p-value < 2.2e-16`

Comment: You are asking a (simplified) one-dimensional version of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40928/measure-the-uniformity-of-distribution-of-points-in-a-2d-square, all of whose answers are applicable to your question with essentially no change at all.

Comment: @whuber, thank you for pointing me to that question. But i must admit that this part of statistics is a bit rusty in my mind, can you be a bit more specific? Thanks.

Comment: [A Baumann](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/40929) suggests a KS-test: read about it on Wikipedia and find an open-source implementation in `R`. [Ben Allison](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/40935) recommends a chi-squared test and helpfully describes how to conduct it by dividing the range of data "into equally sized non-overlapping patches." Many sources, including [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit#Pearson.27s_chi-squared_test), describe this test and provide formulas. Open source software such as `R` will do the calculations automatically.

Comment: @whuber, i have tried to apply `chisq.test` to my dataset and get following result `X-squared = 1664769844, df = 999998, p-value < 2.2e-16`. What does the `df` represent? I will look into `KS-test`.

Comment: You may have misapplied it (although it's conceivable this result is correct): in an edit to your question, can you provide some details describing what you did?  `df` is the **D** egrees of **F** reedom mentioned in all the references.

Comment: @whuber, the `DF` is almost equal to my dataset $N=10^6$.

Comment: That's what I suspected. It means you're misapplying the test, because you have not binned the data as described in the answers I linked to, but it also shows you're on the right track.  With your edits, the question has become clearer and definite, so I'm confident it will get some great answers soon. If you could provide an example of your data--such as the first five or ten lines of the file--that would be even more helpful.

Comment: @whuber, i have provided a small sample of the data.

Comment: One last question (I hope!)  In principle it makes a difference if you know the range of the data beforehand. That is, do you want to check for uniformity within a *predetermined* range of values or do you want both to *estimate* what the range seems to be and *also* check for uniformity?  (The "in principle" would be relevant to smaller datasets: with a million values, the distinction is not likely of practical importance.) Another detail: are all values necessarily integral? Although this is another minor point, it is one that can affect the validity of the test even with a million values.

Comment: @whuber, im working with algorithms that requires RNG's and as far as for the interval is $[0:10^4]$. I do not require that the values are equally divided in the interval. Basically it could be interesting to measure how uniform the values are in the interval and also how uniform it is generally for the dataset (as i can see in the histogram).

Comment: I think your question has been answered in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4331, and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30.

Comment: @whuber, im not really interested in determining the randomness, so Diehard is somewhat out of the picture. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4331/uniform-distribution-test seems useful, but pretty much similiar to my question and failure using `chi-square`.

Comment: Because the idea of randomness includes uniformity--and uniformity is so basic to randomness--all tests of randomness include tests of uniformity. That's why you will find your question answered in those threads about testing randomness.

Comment: @whuber, that is infact true, i might be moving in a wrong direction. But i find this field very confusing. I understand that Diehard is pretty much deprecated, but the alternatives are massive. Is there a particular recommended way to test randomness?

Comment: I see that chi-square is also recommended, but why is my approach failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chi-squared is used in a LOT of ways in statistics. The R command `chisq.test` is described as: "chisq.test performs chi-squared contingency table tests and goodness-of-fit tests." And in particular, "If x ... is a vector and y is not given, then a goodness-of-fit test is performed (x is treated as a one-dimensional contingency table)." So if your $x$ is your raw data, you're getting nonsensical results.

It sounds like you're conflicted on what you're calling "uniform". Visually, you're looking at a histogram, which bins the data in intervals and displays the counts in each interval. Yet you don't require numbers to be equally divided in your interval?

Based on what you're seeing in the histogram, you should bin your data, as in the histogram's bins, and then you can do a `chisq.test` on that, or look at the variance among the bins, or look at quantiles of the bins, or something else.

From what you've said, the big difference between what you want and checking a random number generator is that you don't care about the order in which the numbers were generated, only the set of numbers that were generated. In which case, you'd expect the count of numbers in each bin to be proportional to the size of the bins, and deviance from that would indicate non-uniformity.

Comment: I have realised that my approach to uniform values perhaps has been false. You mention binning my data, can you please explain how i should input the data to `chisq.test`? The doc http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/chisq.test.html does not explain in detail how the data should be.

Comment: @JavaCake: There are various means for binning data. If you're using the `hist` function to generate your histograms, it does more than just graph, and you can do something like: `foo <- hist (x)` and then `chisq.test (foo$counts)`. That is, the count of how many numbers fall into each bin -- indicated by a bar in the graph -- is what you analyze. The `hist` command may not create as many bins as you need, and it only works on the data you present so it doesn't know if there really should be bins to the left or right of your existing data.

Comment: That gave infact a result. Since my interval is $[1:10^4]$ would the chisq function need this information in order to give the correct result?

Comment: My idea was to set `breaks=max` for `hist` and overcome that problem with not getting all bins?

Comment: @JavaCake: I'd look at `cut` and `table` instead of leaning on `hist`, but you need to tell `hist` what your actual range is. Something like: `foo <- hist (x, breaks=seq (1, 10000, length.out=10))` Which says your data ranges from 1 to 10000 and it should be broken up into 10 bins. You should look at the documentation for `seq` (type `?seq`) for more details.

Comment: @JavaCake: If I understand `hist`, `breaks=max` is saying that it should find the maximum number in your input and use that as the number of bins to break your data into. You need to slow down a bit and understand what you're doing a bit more.

Comment: I am trying to put the puzzle together concerning how data should be input in `chisq.test`. I thought that all values in the dataset had to have its own bin and duplicates were summed up in that particular bin in order to get the correct statistical result?

Comment: @JavaCake: No, the values that fall into a bin (a range of x vaules) are counted. Depending on what function you use to calculate and plot a histogram, it may give "density" or "Frequency"/"Count". The default for `hist`, if the bins are all equal-width, is "Frequency", which is the number of x's that fell within each bin (range).

Comment: that makes good sense, im trying to mess around with `cut` and i see the `chisq.test` results change significantly depending on the size of bins/breaks i use. As an example i used `10` which gave me `X-squared = 5.1192, df = 8, p-value = 0.7448` and `1000` which gave me `X-squared = 1087.253, df = 998, p-value = 0.02524`. The last probability is at a level where it does not make sense for my null hypothesis. You mention that only values that fall into a bin is counted, so if i set my break to `10000` there is a chance that all values can have an independent bin?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you're after a measure of uniformity, goodness of fit tests for the uniform offer a variety of statistics that can provide suitable 'uniformity' measures.

If your upper and lower limits are known, Kolomogorov-Smirnov, Cramer-von Mises or Anderson-Darling statistics offer measures of uniformity (though there are a bunch of other measures available from other statistics).

If the upper and lower limits are unknown, you could do correlation against uniform scores ([expected uniform order statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29#Order_statistics) or similar), which doesn't depend on the limits being known.

An alternative is to use the sample max and min to scale the remainder of the sample to $(0,1)$; if the sample is from a uniform that rescaling leaves you with a standard uniform sample with two fewer observations; then one of the goodness-of-fit statistics can be used as a measure of uniformity.

Chi-square test statistics *can* be used but they don't make efficient use of the available information (they have relatively low power against interesting alternatives).